# Why does my custom TextField reset to its default value when content is deleted?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, react-number-format

I created a custom `FormCurrencyField` that uses MUI `TextField`, react-number-format `NumericFormat`, and react-hook-form `useController`.

It works: the values are correctly formatted as currencies and the form model is correctly updated.

The issue I am having with it is that if I delete the content of the TextField, it gets re-set with the default value. I cannot figure out why.

Here is a demo of the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-odfkwv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `defaultValues`, this is shown when there is no values. Instead of that use `values` like so :

```js
const {
    control,
    formState,
    formState: { isValidating },
  } = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange',
    values: { price: 1000 },
  });
```

Comment: ahhh of course.. somehow I thought default values are just the initial values

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValues` is what the form field should reset to when the field is empty. If you want the behaviour where the field resets to an empty field when content is cleared or deleted, replace `defaultValues` with `values` in the `useForm` options.

Comment: could you help here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172208/save-form-values-in-reactjs-using-checkboxes