# Save Form values in ReactJS using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I created a form component using react hook forms. The component is composed from a group of checkboxes and a text input. The text input appears when user click on the last checkbox `custom`. The idea of this one is: when the user will click on it appears a text input and the user can add a custom answer/option. Ex: if user type `test` within the input then when the user will save the form, there should appear in an array `test` value, but `custom` text should't be in the array. In my application i don't have access to `const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data, "submit");`, so i need to change the values within `Component` component. Now when i click on submit i get in the final array the `custom` value. 
 Question: how to fix the issue described above?

```
const ITEMS = [
  { id: "one", value: 1 },
  { id: "two", value: 2 },
  { id: "Custom Value", value: "custom" }
];

export default function App() {
  const name = "group";
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data, "submit");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Component ITEMS={ITEMS} name={name} />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export const Component = ({ name, ITEMS }) => {
  const { control, getValues } = useFormContext();
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const handleCheck = (val) => {
    const { [name]: ids } = getValues();

    const response = ids?.includes(val)
      ? ids?.filter((id) => id !== val)
      : [...(ids ?? []), val];

    return response;
  };

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field, formState }) => {
        return (
          <>
            {ITEMS.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <label>
                    {item.id}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      name={`${name}[${index}]`}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        field.onChange(handleCheck(e.target.value));
                        if (index === ITEMS.length - 1) {
                          setState(e.target.checked);
                        }
                      }}
                      value={item.value}
                    />
                  </label>
                  {state && index === ITEMS.length - 1 && (
                    <input
                      {...control.register(`${name}[${index}]`)}
                      type="text"
                    />
                  )}
                </>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-brook-sml0ww?file=/src/Component.js:151-1600

Comment: It looks like you already got that working. I verified using that link that on submit the text the user typed in the custom field is what is being logged to the console. Maybe I did not understand your question. Are you trying to prevent seeing the "custom" text once the field is made visible?

Comment: @codejockie, try this: select all checkboxes and add text in input, after submit, then deselect one checkbox and submit , you will see that values are not saved correctly. Did you find the issue?

Comment: @codejockie, could you help please?

Comment: I have slightly modified your code. Please see the following link for the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-aryabhata-7jprlr?file=/src/Custom.js

Comment: @codejockie, how to get an array of values? Example: `[first, second, inputValue]`

Comment: @codejockie If there are not checked data, when the user will submit he should get an emty array `[]`

Comment: @codejockie, and also will be very helpful to use Controller as in my example, could you help please?

Comment: @codejockie, could you help?

Comment: I have busy and I have not had a look again, not sure I will.

Comment: so what's the expected final result I'll write the code in new answer, what should be the final result when you print the data on submit?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the goal is to keep all the selections in the same `group` field, which must be an array that logs the selected values in provided order, with the custom input value as the last item if specified, perhaps ideally it would be easier to calculate the values in `onSubmit` before submitting.

But since the preference is not to add logic in `onSubmit`, maybe an alternative option could be hosting a local state, run the needed calculations when it changes, and call `setValue` manually to sync the calculated value to the `group` field.

Forked demo with modification: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-form-checkbox-state-host-ddqg9d?file=/src/Component.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const Component = ({ name, ITEMS }) => {
  const { control, setValue } = useFormContext();
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const { custom, ...items } = state;
    const newItems = Object.entries(items).filter((item) => !!item[1]);
    newItems.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
    const newValues = newItems.map((item) => item[1]);
    if (custom) {
      setValue(name, [...newValues, custom]);
      return;
    }
    setValue(name, [...newValues]);
  }, [name, state, setValue]);

  const handleCheck = (val, idx) => {
    setState((prev) =>
      prev[idx] ? { ...prev, [idx]: null } : { ...prev, [idx]: val }
    );
  };

  const handleCheckCustom = (checked) =>
    setState((prev) =>
      checked ? { ...prev, custom: "" } : { ...prev, custom: null }
    );

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, custom: e.target.value }));
  };

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field, formState }) => {
        return (
          <>
            {ITEMS.map((item, index) => {
              const isCustomField = index === ITEMS.length - 1;
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  <label>
                    {item.id}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      name={name}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        isCustomField
                          ? handleCheckCustom(e.target.checked)
                          : handleCheck(e.target.value, index)
                      }
                      value={item.value}
                    />
                  </label>
                  {typeof state["custom"] === "string" && isCustomField && (
                    <input onChange={handleInputChange} type="text" />
                  )}
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a while I got the solution. I forked your sandbox and did little changes, check it out here: [Save Form values in ReactJS using checkboxes](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-black-7sehs2?file=/src/Component.js)

Basically, you should have an internal checkbox state and also don't register the input in the form, because this would add the input value to the end of the array no matter if that value is "".

Here is the code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Component = ({ name, ITEMS }) => {
  const { control, setValue } = useFormContext();
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState(
    ITEMS.filter(
      (item, index) => index !== ITEMS.length - 1
    ).map(({ value }, index) => ({ value, checked: false }))
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(name, []); //To initialize the array as empty
  }, []);

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const handleChangeField = (val) => {
    const newCheckboxes = checkboxes.map(({ value, checked }) =>
      value == val ? { value, checked: !checked } : { value, checked }
    );
    setCheckboxes(newCheckboxes);

    const response = newCheckboxes
      .filter(({ checked }) => checked)
      .map(({ value }) => value);
    return state && !!inputValue ? [...response, inputValue] : response;
  };

  const handleChangeInput = (newInputValue) => {
    const response = checkboxes
      .filter(({ checked }) => checked)
      .map(({ value }) => value);
    if (state) if (!!newInputValue) return [...response, newInputValue];
    return response;
  };

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field, formState }) => {
        return (
          <>
            {ITEMS.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <label>
                    {item.id}
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      name={`${name}[${index}]`}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        if (index === ITEMS.length - 1) {
                          setState(e.target.checked);
                          return;
                        }
                        field.onChange(handleChangeField(e.target.value));
                      }}
                      value={item.value}
                    />
                  </label>
                  {state && index === ITEMS.length - 1 && (
                    <input
                      value={inputValue}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setInputValue(e.target.value);
                        field.onChange(handleChangeInput(e.target.value));
                      }}
                      type="text"
                    />
                  )}
                </>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```