# Adding a value from text input using spread operator in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form where i need to save the values as an array:

```
function App() {
  const {
    setValue,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data, "submit");
  }; // your form submit function which will invoke after successful validation
  const allValues = watch("example") || [];
  console.log(allValues);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {[1, 2, 3].map((v, index) => {
        return (
          <input value={v} type="checkbox" {...register(`example[${index}]`)} />
        );
      })}

      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue("example", e.target.value);
        }}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here: `setValue("example", e.target.value);` i want to set my text input value inside the result, so when i add check some checkboxes like 1 and 2 and also add `test` value in text input, when i will save i need to get the next result `[1,2,'test']`. If there is not a value in text input i should't add anything in the array.
 question: How to solve the issue? Now if i add `test` in array i get `[t,e,s,t]`. 
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-q2xhj5?file=/src/index.js:129-840

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const { setValue, getValues, register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (inputValue) setValue("example", [...getValues().example, inputValue]);
    console.log(getValues().example);
  }; // your form submit function which will invoke after successful validation

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {[1, 2, 3].map((v, index) => {
        return (
          <input value={v} type="checkbox" {...register(`example[${index}]`)} />
        );
      })}

      <input
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setInputValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

This is my solution. Some changes I made:

1. I only add the input value to the "example" array `onSubmit`, not `onChange`.
2. I made the input controlled, giving it a value property `inputValue`, and setting it in the `onChange` handler
3. I made use of `getValues` function, to obtain the current elements of `example` array. Then I used `setValue` with the *spread operator* to add at the end of the array.

Feel free to ask me further questions!

--Ado

Edit 1: turns out I got it wrong, you don't want to add the input value to example every time on submit. Here is my new solution:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const {  getValues, register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(getValues().example);
  }; // your form submit function which will invoke after successful validation
  const checkboxes = [1, 2, 3];
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {checkboxes.map((v, index) => {
        return (
          <input value={v} type="checkbox" {...register(`example[${index}]`)} />
        );
      })}

      <input
      {...register(`example[${checkboxes.length}]`)}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: thank you, but the code does not work as expected, if i add text input value and sumbmit many times the result every time is different.

Comment: Ok so I made some changes, I thought you wanted to add the value every time.

Comment: I would also recommend that you add a `key` attribute to every checkbox, so you don't have the warning "every child must have a unique key". That's only a suggestion!
For example: `<input key={v}  type="checkbox" {...register(example[${index}])} />`.
Also, I don't think you need the `value` property for the checkboxes, it's not that common to have a checkbox with a value of "1", "2" or "3", checkboxes are meant to have a value of `true` or `false`.

Comment: i have a question also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172208/save-form-values-in-reactjs-using-checkboxes , could you help please? It will help me a lot

Comment: please let me know when you have any results

Comment: The idea is next, I have an array of checkboxes, when the user will click on the third one there should appear a text input where can be added any text, after submitting the form the user should get an array  of strings, but without the third checkbox, so the third checkbox value should be the value from the input. Did you get the idea?

Comment: I answered you in your other post